# pgAdmin cannot find records while SQLAlchemy does

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, pgadmin

pgAdmin does not find records in users table while SQLAlchemy does. I have a web app that is storing user credentials in AWS postgres database.  The app works fine. Selecting * from postgres returns the table name but no records. When connecting via SQLalchemy I get the results I expect.

New to postgres so I've tried using quotes and a several other queries.

This query gives all tables:

```
SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema='public'
AND table_type='BASE TABLE';
```

Results:

```
users
post
user
```

This query doesnt work:

```
SELECT * FROM users;
```

Results:

```
id | username | email | password
---------------------------------
(Blank)
```

SQLAlchemy:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from config import postgresUser, postgresPass
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "Removed for security"  
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, 
    default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy=True)


class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, 
default=datetime.utcnow)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), 
    nullable=False)

users = User.query.all()

for user in users:
    print(user.email) for
```

Gives Results Expected:

```
 jimbo@mail.com
 jane@mail.com
```

I dont know why SQLAchemy can find it but pgAdmin cannot. Other queries for the post table seem to work.

Using: Flask, SQLAlchemy, AWS postgres. Running on local machine.

Comment: Double check if you use different databases, different schemas or have uncommitted transactions.

Comment: I only have 1 database. It appears I'm using 1 schema and the transactions are all handled by my app.  If there were uncommitted changes my app wouldn't log anyone in. SQLAlchemy finds the records just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: 
The issue was SQLAlchemy creates a table named 'user' from class 'User'.  user is a reserved table in Postgres. In pgAdmin I only see a single user table in the sidebar. My user table is accessible via query by adding double quotes. SELECT * FROM "user";

Don't use SQLAlchemy class User or user for postgres. I renamed my class Users. Hope it helps others.